# How can I write a VBA Loop to run multiple modules for a list of customer numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to automate the creation of customer reporting. I have written the module to update the customer list, the module to create each section of the report for a single customer and the module to save the data to a separate file. I have been unsuccessful in writing the loop to move to the next customer number and rerun the modules for each customer in the list.

I have tried to loop through all of the customer numbers to create separate files. Only the first customer number gets populated, then the cell is blank but the process continues to create new files. I stop the process when the second blank file asks if I want to over write the first blank file.

```
Sub Update_All()

Sheet5.Select

Dim FindLastRow As String
    FindLastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = FindLastRow


For r = 2 To LastRow

Dim TPAID_Autorun As String
TPAID_Autorun = Cells(r, 1)

Sheet4.Range("C4").Value = "'" & TPAID_Autorun

'This line was used to test the loop
'MsgBox Sheet4.Range("C4").Value


Call RefreshPayorSummary
Call ExceptionsToResolve
Call RefreshPayeeSummary
Call RefreshNonProfitTINs
Call RefreshCorrectedTINs
Call SaveClientFile


Next r

End 
End Sub
```

I am hoping to have all of the files created and the process stop when the customer number is blank.

Comment: If the `TPAID_Autorun = Cells(r, 1)` should always refer to what's on `Sheet5`, then you need to qualify it as such -- it seems likely that at least one of your other `Call` procedures is changing the active worksheet/workbook, and as a result the global `Cells` always refers to *whatever worksheet is active*, unless qualified to a book/sheet.

Comment: `TPAID_Autorun = ThisWorkbook.Sheet5.Cells(r, 1)`. If that still doesn't solve the problem, then you'll need to provide an [mcve]. Right now you're calling 6 other functions/subs that are, effectively for anyone trying to help you, black holes. We have no idea what those are doing or how they're altering the environment during runtime, and without that information, may not be possible to answer fully.

Comment: I went back through all of the call procedures to made sure they were returning to Sheet4 cell C4 (some of them were going back to cell C5). Then I added "Sheet5" to the TPAID_Autorun line and it worked perfectly. Thank you!!!!